# verilog ram question debugging verilog code for ram unit please help need 15 characters

Tags: verilog, ram

`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module DataMemory(
input [31:0] Address,
input [31:0] Writedata,
input MemRead,
input MemWrite,
output [31:0] ReadData
);

```
 reg [0:31] mem[15:0];
           mem[0] = 32'haaaaaaaa;          
           mem[1] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[2] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[3] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[4] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[5] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[6] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[7] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[8] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[9] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[10] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[11] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[12] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[13] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[14] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[15] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
```

begin

```
process(MemWrite, MemRead) // pulse on write
begin 
    if (MemWrite = '1' ) then
        DM(    (    to_integer(unsigned(Address)) - 268500992)/4 <= WriteData;
        end if;   
       
    if ( MemRead = '1') then
        ReadData <= DM(     ( to_integer(unsigned(Address)) - 268500992   ) /4     );
        end if;
```

I am debugging this code and cannot figure out why the lines do not work:

```
 reg [0:31] mem[15:0];
           mem[0] = 32'haaaaaaaa;          
           mem[1] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[2] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[3] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[4] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[5] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[6] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[7] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[8] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[9] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[10] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[11] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[12] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[13] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[14] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
           mem[15] = 32'haaaaaaaa;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to guess that you are trying to initialize the array. You can do that using this syntax:

```
reg [0:31] mem[15:0] = '{
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa,
    32'haaaaaaaa};
```